# Multiple Producer Multiple Resources One Cosumer

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, concurrency, producer-consumer

I am newbie to Java concurrency. I have learned about producer consumer pattern where one producer write on a vector and consumer consumed it from the vector. But I have to make a homework with some different situations where-

1. Two producers independently write on 2 separate vector - odd and even number.
2. One consumer read from each of the vector and sum up them.

Can anyone suggest any tutorial that fit with the scenario? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you supposed to use an specific algorithm? (Semaphores, Messages, Monitors), I think it's a multiple-semaphore problem.

Comment: @user3514678 Do not forget that if an answer solves  your question satisfactorily, you can [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235/227183).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest the following tutorials:

- [Java Concurrency / Multithreading Tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/index.html)
- [Java concurrency (multi-threading) - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html)
- [Java Concurrent Animated](http://www.jconcurrent.com/Overview.html)

Videos in YouTube:

- [Concurrency (Multithreading) Concepts in Java](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RHoP92anvxY)
- [Concurrency Without Pain in Pure Java](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2jFpFGAwcU)
- [Java Tutorial : How to use Threads(Concurrent),Synchronized Keyword and Semaphores -](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWTZwTPuvdM)